# ASP.NET checkbox value store in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net

I using FormView in my application. I found that no value property in asp checkbox is available! Following code for my check box (it displays True/False values from SQL Server).

So I just need to be able to add True/False or "on" value from checkbox to database when I saves form.

Thanks for help.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" 
              CssClass="checkbox"   
              Text="Medicine"
              ID="lic_board_medicine_chk" 
              TextAlign="Right" 
Checked='<%# Eval("lic_board_medicine_chk").ToString() == "True" ? true : false%>'/>
```

Comment: When going through your checkboxes you need to check the .checked attribute (true/false), there is no value property in the checkbox anymore. This might help: [http://forums.asp.net/t/946448.aspx/1](http://forums.asp.net/t/946448.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

try changing **Eval** to **BIND**

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" 
              CssClass="checkbox"   
              Text="Medicine"
              ID="lic_board_medicine_chk" 
              TextAlign="Right" 
Checked='<%# Bind("lic_board_medicine_chk").ToString() == "True" ? "checked" : "" %>'/>
```

Comment: OP is looking for checked property actually.

Comment: Bind gives me an error: CS0103: The name 'BIND' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user1202420 Bind not BIND . try now.

Comment: @user1202420 Are you using  SqlDataAdapter ?

Comment: Yes, I did both. First i use Bind, then in second try I used BIND (I know the BIND is incorrect, however tryied both just in case :).

Comment: I using SQL Database as Source Type.

Comment: let me understnad : do you see the checkbox on the page ? or not ? or you have troube in saving the Checkbox ?

Comment: Yes, I see the check box in form, but when I replace my statment(Eval with Bind) page gives me an error.